# How to truncate input in the Huggingface pipeline?

Tags: huggingface-transformers, huggingface-tokenizers

I currently use a huggingface pipeline for sentiment-analysis like so:

```
from transformers import pipeline
classifier = pipeline('sentiment-analysis', device=0)
```

The problem is that when I pass texts larger than 512 tokens, it just crashes saying that the input is too long.  Is there any way of passing the max_length and truncate parameters from the tokenizer directly to the pipeline?

My work around is to do:

from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModelForSequenceClassification

```
model_name = "nlptown/bert-base-multilingual-uncased-sentiment"
model = AutoModelForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained(model_name)
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_name)
classifier = pipeline('sentiment-analysis', model=model, tokenizer=tokenizer, device=0)
```

And then when I call the tokenizer:

```
pt_batch = tokenizer(text, padding=True, truncation=True, max_length=512, return_tensors="pt")
```

But it would be much nicer to simply be able to call the pipeline directly like so:

```
classifier(text, padding=True, truncation=True, max_length=512)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

this way should work:

```
classifier(text, padding=True, truncation=True)
```

if it doesn't try to load tokenizer as:

```
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_name, model_max_len=512)
```

Comment: I think it should be model_max_length instead of model_max_len. Otherwise it doesn't work for me.

Comment: I had to use max_len=512 to make it work.

Answer (score 26):

you can use tokenizer_kwargs while inference :

```
model_pipline = pipeline("text-classification",model=model,tokenizer=tokenizer,device=0, return_all_scores=True)

tokenizer_kwargs = {'padding':True,'truncation':True,'max_length':512,'return_tensors':'pt'}

prediction = model_pipeline('sample text to predict',**tokenizer_kwargs)
```

for more details you can check this [link](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/master/src/transformers/pipelines/text_classification.py#:%7E:text=def%20preprocess(self%2C%20inputs%2C%20**tokenizer_kwargs)%20%2D%3E%20Dict%5Bstr%2C%20GenericTensor%5D%3A)

Comment: Thanks. This works with regular Python. I am trying it in PySpark. Where would you place the tokenizer_kwargs - when creating the udf or when calling the udf? if you can give me an example for pyspark, I would appreciate it. Thanks.

schema = ArrayType(StructType([
  StructField("score", FloatType(), True),
  StructField("label", StringType(), True)
]))

...
...
tokenizer_kwargs = {'padding': True, 'truncation': True, 'max_length': 512}


sentiment_udf = F.udf(model_pipeline, schema)
df = df.withColumn('pred_label', sentiment_udf(F.col("text")))

Answer (score 1):

This is the way:

```
from transformers import pipeline
generator = pipeline(task='text2text-generation', truncation=True, model=model, tokenizer=tokenizer)

# check your result
generator._preprocess_params
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ export TRANSFORMERS_CACHE=/projectnb/pnn/.cache
$ export HF_HOME=/projectnb/pnn/.cache
$ export HF_DATASETS_CACHE=/projectnb/pnn/.cache
```

This one works for me. Please change `/projectnb/pnn/.cache` to your own path.