# Huggingface TextClassifcation pipeline: truncate text size

Tags: python, huggingface-transformers

I'm trying to use text_classification pipeline from Huggingface.transformers to perform sentiment-analysis, but some texts exceed the limit of 512 tokens. I want the pipeline to truncate the exceeding tokens automatically. I tried the approach from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67849833/how-to-truncate-input-in-the-huggingface-pipeline) thread, but it did not work

Here is my code:

```
nlp= pipeline('sentiment-analysis',
                     model=AutoModelForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained(
                        "model",
                         return_dict=False),
                     tokenizer=AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(
                         "model",
                         return_dict=False),
                     framework="pt", return_all_scores=False)

output = nlp(article)
```

Answer (score 1):

In order anyone faces the same issue, here is how I solved it:

```
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("model", return_dict=False)

nlp= pipeline('sentiment-analysis',
                     model=AutoModelForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained(
                        "model",
                         return_dict=False),
                     tokenizer=tokenizer,
                     framework="pt", return_all_scores=False)

encoded_input = tokenizer(article, truncation=True, max_length=512)
decoded_input = tokenizer.decode(encoded_input["input_ids"], skip_special_tokens = True)
output = nlp(decoded_input)
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, and a more direct way to solve this issue, you can simply specify those parameters as `**kwargs` in the pipeline:

```py
from transformers import pipeline

nlp = pipeline("sentiment-analysis")
nlp(long_input, truncation=True, max_length=512)
```

Comment: I realize this has also been suggested as an answer in the other thread; if it doesn't work, please specify *why* it does not work in your case, i.e., what the error message i.s

Comment: Using this approach did not work. Meaning, the text was not truncated up to 512 tokens.
I read somewhere that, when a pre_trained model used, the arguments I pass won't work (truncation, max_length). Maybe that's the case. I'm not sure.

Comment: How can you tell that the text was not truncated?

Comment: Well, because the `nlp(long_input, truncation=True, max_length=512)` throws the same error as `nlp(long_input)` --- tensor a is > tensor b